# Twilio SendMessage c#

Tags: c#, twilio

Dont seem to be getting any sms sent back, account is in trial mode, but ive added my number to verified numbers, any ideas?

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SmsRequest(FormCollection form)
    {   
    var model = new Models.SMSRequest();
    model.From = form["From"];
    //more code
    string AccountSid = "GUID";
    string AuthToken = "GUID";
    var client = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
    //0000 = twilio assigned number
    var result = client.SendMessage("00000", model.From, "Thank you for your SMS");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, you need to ensure the sms number (sending from) is in the following format 
client.SendMessage("+44 0000 000000", model.From, "Body")